# Aura Lightning On Change

Tags: lightning, aura, onchange

I have a Lightning component `ui:inputSelect`, and I'm trying to capture an `OnChange`.It appears that it very well documented to do it but I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've tried many different iterations but my `selectedValue` always comes back `undefined`

**Markup**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pickListTitle" type="String"/>

    <div>
        <ui:inputSelect label="{!v.pickListTitle}" class="dynamic" aura:id="optionItems" change="{!c.onChange}" value="{!v.selectedValue}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

My `buildOptions` in my helper works fine, ill post it anyway just for context

**Helper**

```
buildOptions : function(component) {
    var body = component.get("v.options"); 

    var options = [];

    for(var i=0; i < body.length; i++){
        options.push({"class": "optionClass", label: body[i], value: body[i]});
    }

    component.find("optionItems").set("v.options", options);    
}
```

I've tried so many different things in my controller to capture this change, and this iteration may be completely incorrect, does anyone have any guidance?

**Controller**

```
onChange: function(component, event) {
    var selectCmp = component.find("optionItems");
    resultCmp.set("v.selectedValue", selectCmp.get("v.selectedValue"));
    console.log('+ selectCmp' + selectCmp.get("v.selectedValue"))
}
```

Comment: You don't need to capture the change for this purpose, because of two way binding. As such, I suspect this may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you should ask a question about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component has the `v.selectedValue` attribute (whereas `ui:inputSelect` has a `v.value`attribute) so in your `onChange` it would be:

```
component.get("v.selectedValue")
```

to access that value not:

```
selectCmp.get("v.selectedValue")
```

My first guess is that the `onChange` method may not even be needed assuming there is two-way binding. You could check that with this just for debug purposes:

```
onChange: function(component, event) {
    console.log('selected=' + component.get("v.selectedValue"))
}
```

If the method is needed, I'd expect it to look more like this:

```
onChange: function(component, event) {
    var select = component.find("optionItems");
    component.set("v.selectedValue", select.get("v.value"));
    console.log('selected=' + component.get("v.selectedValue"))
}
```

Comment: You're right that two-way binding should take care of things.